# How to choose a random word from a list of words in racket?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I want to choose a random word from a list-of-words and possibly present it hidden by *.I am completely new and finding it hard to create codes in racket after practicing python. The code I have tried is-

(define (random-word)
(list-ref
list-of-words
(length list-of-words (make-string (random 10) #*))))

then-

> (random-word)
> . . length: arity mismatch;
> the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
> expected: 1
> given: 2

if i write this-
(define (random-word)
(list-ref
list-of-words
(modulo
(contract-random-generate (or/c exact-nonnegative-integer?))
(length list-of-words))))
then-
contract-random-generate not defined.

I am actually just trying random codes to see if things work out or not but in any way I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but not very efficient way is to use [`shuffle`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._shuffle%29%29) and take the first element of the result.

```lisp
(define (random-word lst) (first (shuffle lst)))
```

A better approach would be to [generate a random number in the range `[0, length of list)`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._random%29%29), and use [`list-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29) to return that element. It ends up not being much longer than the above version:

```lisp
(define (random-word lst) (list-ref lst (random (length lst))))
```

Comment: Well I have tried this and it's working.  (define (random-word) (list-ref list-of-words (random (length list-of-words)))) . But can u tell how I can hide the word with *?

Comment: What do you mean by hide?

Comment: When displaying a list (PIck a random element. Display each element of the list in turn, except that one) or replacing it in the list with a string of *'s?

Answer (score 0):

> I am actually just trying random codes to see if things work out or not but in any way I can't.

So-called [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) should be avoided at any cost. You are cheating yourself of understanding and sound reasoning techniques to solve problems in a fundamental way.

```scm
(define (hide-random-elem ls)
  (let ((len (length ls)))
    (let loop ((ls ls) (ref (random 0 len)))
      (if (= ref 0)
          (cons '* (cdr ls))
          (cons (car ls) (loop (cdr ls) (- ref 1)))))))
```

```scm
(define my-list '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o))

(hide-random-elem my-list)
```

```scm
'(a b c d e f g h i j k l * n o)
```

```scm
(hide-random-elem (hide-random-elem (hide-random-elem my-list)))
```

```scm
'(* b c d e f g h i * k l m n *) ; may or may not contain 3 *'s
```

**recommended reading**

- [The Little Schemer](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-schemer-fourth-edition) By Daniel P. Friedman and Matthias Felleisen
- [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) By Harold Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman
- [How To Design Programs](http://htdp.org) By Mathias Felleisen, Robert Bruce Findler, Matthew Flatt, Shriram Krishnamurthi

Comment: While I agree the copy and paste code from SO in ones profession is a real problem, I learned a lot from editing parts of my Dragon32 and C64 programs when I was young, often written verbatim from a journal, and then I change parts of it to see what happened with the result. SICP exercises are usually modifying an example tt achieve a new  feature.